# How do I cut off a decimal without rounding?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to cut off decimals without rounding the last digit.

For example, if my number is `1394.95861`, I would like it to show `1.39` - I don't want the last `9` to round up to a 0 or round down to an 8.

I've tried round, number_format, and all of those, but they all just round the last digit up.

```
if($number >= '1000') {

        $result = number_format(($number / 1000), 2);
        return $result;
}
```

Comment: What is your number? If you have 1394.95861 the result should be 1.39

Comment: @sectus Yes, that's correct. My example was merely one that people could relate to, it wasn't directly related to my code.

Comment: why not convert it to string and substring it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use `>= '1000'` since that treats `$number` as a string.

Try this:

```
if($number >= 1000) {
  $num = floor($number / 10) / 100;
  $result = number_format($num, 2);
  return $result . 'k';
}
```

I modified that based off of your question and code, but the key thing is `floor` being used to drop the remaining decimal points (hence why I divide by 10 first), then divide by those you wanted to keep (the divide by 100) to get your number.

EDIT: Calculational example

`$number = 123456789.987654321;`

Then, `$number >= 1000` is true.

`$number / 10` = `12345678.9987654321`

And, the floor is

`12345678`

Divided by 100, we get

`123456.78`

Then, run through number format to get

`123,456.78`

And then add a `k` for the result:

`123,456.78k`

Modified code per chat:

```
function shorten_number($number) { 
  if($number >= 1000000000) { 
    $result = floor($number / 10000000) / 100; 
    return number_format($result) . 'b'; 
  } elseif($number >= 1000000) { 
    $num = floor($number / 10000) / 100; 
    $result = number_format($num, 2); 
    return $result . 'm'; 
  } elseif($number >= 1000) { 
    $num = floor($number / 10) / 100; 
    $result = number_format($num, 2); 
    return $result . 'k'; 
  } elseif($number < 1000) { 
    $result = $number; 
    return $result; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything with the output, it still shows the same result.

Comment: Your edit helps.  Let me adjust the answer since now it is less ambiguous.

Comment: How exactly does this work? When I edit the code to also with with millions, it doesn't work, though the thousands do. Mind explaining to me so I understand for future use?

Comment: `floor` is a function which says "drop all of the decimals".  This will work with whatever you throw at it *except* a string.  So, if you have "1,000,000" instead of "1000000", it will have problems -- is that what you're working with?  If so, the fix is easy, just let me know.

Comment: No, it only deals with numbers. It comes in as a string and it gets rid of all other information from it other than numeric characters.

Comment: Then what are you inputting?  I'll update my example with a large number to demonstrate what I am talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61092/discussion-between-ted-mosby-and-jeremy-miller).

Answer (score 1):

do it manually -

```
$num = 12345.6789;

$number = explode('.', $num);

if (isset($number[1])) {
    if (isset($number[1][0])) {
        $number[0] .= '.'.$number[1][0];
        if (isset($number[1][1])) {
            $number[0] .= $number[1][1];
        }
    }
}
echo (float) $number[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Main idea is: create integer digit with proper digits using `floor`.

```
$number = 1394958.61;
if($number >= '1000') {

        $result = number_format((floor($number /10)/100), 2);
        echo $result . 'k';
}
```

Or using type casting.

```
        $result = number_format((intval($number /10)/100), 2);
```